lost "target value" role after merge data
Hello there,
Currently i am trying to learn Orange how to classify the quality of products we produce b image analysis.
I have a set of images which i analyse via image embedding. This gives 1 dataset.
Then i have an exxel file containing the quality scores of the products in each picure and the filname of that picture. The quality column i have given  "target" as role when importing.
Then i erge the two datasets using the "merge data" wiget. The resulting dataset does not seem to have a target value anymore (when i try to load that into a neural network or any other modelling widget).
Where do i go wrong? How can i get the image data and the quality score into 1 dataset to feed to a model?
